# Is it possible to go back even after onBackPressed() is overridden?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, android-dialog

I have an activity that does a resource hungry work in a thread(not ui) and after all that is done, It shows a dialog(alert dialog).

To prevent the back button from being pressed, I have overridden the onBackPressed method. There is a backbutton which I have implement that calls finish();

Now, IF the user starts the resource hungry task (by pressing a button) , I am setting the visibility of my own back button to INVISIBLE (and reappear after task is done)

This seems to work fine when I use it , but when I run a monkey tester , I get the following error:

```
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@537aa58c is not valid; is your activity running? 
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:585) 
 08-3014:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547) 
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277) 
 08-30 14:43:26.611:E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932) 
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):    at com.mainpackage.FullGenMaths$3$1$3.run(FullGenMaths.java:169) 
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
 08-30 14:43:26.611:E/AndroidRuntime(1568):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
 08-30 14:43:26.611: E/AndroidRuntime(1568):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The line that caused the crash (line 169) is **`MYDIALOG.show();`**

What is causing this crash ? I suspect that the monkey tester is causing the activity to pause, and start a new activity, and when that paused activity calls dialog.show(), I get this error.

What is the right way to handle this , aside of not keeping track of the visibility of my activity(and accordingly showing the dialog) ?

This is how I am setting up the alert dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(FullGenMaths.this);

                                   // Setting Dialog Title
                                   alertDialog.setTitle("Share your Notes to...");

                                   // Setting Dialog Message
                                   alertDialog.setMessage("Would you like to Email the Generated Paper? ");

                                   // Setting Icon to Dialog


                                   // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                                   alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                                       // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                       bar.setProgress(0);
                                       String[] body={"stackk.overflow@gmail.com"};

                                       Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                                       emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
                                       emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, body); 
                                       emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Marks++ generated paper"); 
                                       emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Generated by Marks++"); 
                                       emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/"+assetfilenamepdf));
                                       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));

                                       }
                                   });

                                   // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                                   alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                       // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO, Paper Saved in "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                       dialog.cancel();
                                       bar.setProgress(0);
                                       }
                                   });

                                   // Showing Alert Message
                                   alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
                                   alertDialog.show();
```

This is the overridden backpressed :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please click on the cross to go back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: how does one edit the error log like that ?

Comment: If you only want avoiding alert beign closed you can call `AlertDialog.Builder.setCancelable(false)`, so maybe with that you don't need to override the onBackPressed

Comment: it is already false.

Comment: @harvey_slash post the code where you intialized your alert dialog

Comment: Also post the overriden backpressed

Comment: Does the activity is finished when the alert dialog is shown?

Comment: no , its not finished

Comment: @harvey_slash can you post the entire class with the thread and the button.

Comment: its too long. I can tell you that its working on a new thread. The buttons become invisible alright

Comment: It is impossible for me to debug the problem. Without seeng the entire code

Comment: Can you tell me if there is ANY way to go back other than pressing the back button ? 
it only happens which i am running the monkey tester

Comment: You can call super.onBackPressed()

Comment: i meant, is it any way for the user to do it

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the answer you will hear, but what you do is just awful for the user. You force him to wait till a job will be done, which takes a fair amount of time, staring at the display. Blocking elementary navigation controls of the device will lead to a deletion of your app by the user.

Consider to use a Service/IntentService for the background operation and provide the results if the calculations are done. This way you don't have to keep the Activity running and the user can use the app in any way and will be informed about a completed task. This should be the way to go.

Comment: for certain reasons, I would WANT the user to stay on in that activity

Comment: The user doesn't care what you want them to do.  If you change the normal behavior of things like the back button, they'll probably just uninstall your app.

Answer (score 1):

As you said that your resource hungry task is in the background, you are supposed to stop it when the activity goes out of focus - in `onStop` that is. Restart it when necessary. See if that helps.

Also, overriding the system behavior is not a good idea.

Comment: Maintain your dialog a global variable and make it visible only if it is not shown. I am guessing that trying to show() a visivle dialog will cause problems